# Force htaccess to redirect for specific requests

Tags: .htaccess

I have the `htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can this be changed to force requests to `/sys-admin` to be redirected into `index.php` even if it does exist (file or directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another rule set:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sys-admin*$

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: does the positioning of the rule matter at all?

Comment: You'd probably want the rule and condition before your other ones. So, right after the "RewriteBase /"